# How to handle multipart/form-data in policy expression of Azure API Management?

Tags: multipartform-data, azure-api-management

I am building an API endpoint in APIM that should accept multipart/form-data and then transform this request to two separate backend API's - one with the form data, and another for file upload.  Is this possible to achieve using Policy templates/expressions?  The policy expression has limited support for types, and hence use of methods such as ReadAsMultipartAsync() is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this isn't supported as of today. There is a [feature request](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/26071d65-0125-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0858) that you can up vote for it to gain traction.

In the meantime, you could have a proxy after APIM and before your APIs, which could separate the form data as required and send them to the separate endpoints as required.